# Why previous commits of other contributors are also pushed along my code changes?

Tags: git

I fetched a new branch from the remote repo that was created recently using:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b newbranchname
```

and a new branch was created

so i have branch named `upstream/newbranchname` but after making changes in it,  committing and pushing it to the remote repo it is pushing the code from the previous commits made by other contributors and that is creating merge conflicts.

I want to just push my changes to the remote repo.

Suppose i just modified `components/card` file and did `git add components/card` but then also the other changes that were pushed previously by other contributors are also getting push along with my push

If anyone has any suggestion please help.

Comment: Could you include the specific commands you executed?

Comment: So I have a forked repo that I forked using the `fork only main branch` option after that I had to work on another branch for for that i used `git fetch upstream` and git `checkout -b web-release-3` after checking `git remote -v` I have two branches as remote `origin` and `upstream` and I got all the branches from the remote repo with `upstream/` as suffix. Then I created a new branch from the upstream/web-release-3 branch using `git checkout -b usecase` and made the changes in it and then added those files commited pushed but when made PR it is including code that was pushed from prev commits

Comment: by other contributors. What should I do to push only my commits. Doing rebase and pushing us giving error as hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind.

Comment: you are probably doing it wrong. Follow these two steps 1) create your branch seperately from master and ensure it is not used by others 2) make the changes and stage your changes and then push your changes.  This will only ensure that your changes are present in the branch also dont take a merge in between from any other branch otherwise you would get their changes too. I hope these two approach works out for you

Comment: Your `git checkout -b` commands, did you specify a source branch, or did you make sure you were on the source branch? For instance, you say "Then I created a new branch from the upstream/web-release-3 branch", how exactly did you make sure it was from that branch, and not just a continuation of whatever it was you had checked out at the time?

Comment: A push cannot create a merge conflict, because a push cannot create a merge. Can you explain how you got a merge conflict in relation to your push? When git merges, it considers all commits not already merged to the target branch, so if you create your branch from the wrong source, it might drag in commits you don't want on the target branch.